# Разделение на страницы контента саита

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, можете посоветовать или может уже есть скрипт готовый для разделения контента сайта на страницы?

Comment: Непонятно, что имеется в виду под "разделением контента сайта на страницы". Может вас интересует "постраничная навигация"?

Comment: Да я знаю, что хромает, но я не из России...
Да постраничная навигация проста, я не знал, что она так называется!

Answer (score 2):

Посмотрите по этим ссылкам:

- [Как разбить вывод из mysql постранично](http://www.phpfaq.ru/paginator)
- [Постраничная навигация (Pagination) средствами jQuery](http://www.codeharmony.ru/materials/16)

А вообще в интернете можете сами посмотреть, сотни примеров. Вбейте в поиск "постраничная навигация" или "pagination".

Comment: Если ответ устраивает, то нажмите кнопочку "Принять ответ" :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?
/*
 *  допустим нам нужна пагинация для news(тобишь новостей)
 *  надо вводить какойто параметр чтобы можно было
 *  как-то определить какая страница нужна и строить ссылки
 *  соответственно. Пуска этим параметром будет $_GET['page']
 *  Накидаю процедурно, если у вы на ООП пишите 
 *  Перенесете сами без проблем
*/

function getFirstPage() {
    //подключаемся к бд...
    $res = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 10');
    $news = array(); //массив для новостей
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
        $news[] = $row;  //ложим новости
    }
    $links = getPaginationLinks();
    $result = array('news'=>$news, 'links'=>$links);
    return $result;
}

function getNews() {
    if($_GET['page'] && $_GET['page'] >= 1) {
        //сразу проверим не равен ли page 1е
        if($_GET['page'] == 1) {
            return getFirstPage();
        }
        else {
            $limit = ($_GET['page']*10-10) . ', 10';
            $res = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT ' . $limit);
            $news = array();
            while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
                  $news[] = $row;
            }
            // проверим, а есть ли новости на этой странице...
            if(empty($news)) {
                 die(); //die я написал для примера, вообще тут обычно делается 404....
            }
            $links = getPaginationLinks(); //получаем данные для наших ссылок
            //  пакуем все в единый массив....
            $result = array('news'=>$news, 'links'=>$links);
            //  в итоге на выходе данные для новостей на этой странице
            //  и ссылки соответственно
            return $result;
        }
    }
    else {
         //допустим нету $_GET['page'] параметра, тогда будем отдавать первую страницу...
         return getFirstPage();
    }
}

function getPaginationLinks() {
    //для начала посчитаем количество всех новостей...
    $res = mysql_query('SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM news');
    $count = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
    $count = $count['count'];
    // начнем уже формировать необходимые данные...
    $links = array();
        // допустим что у нас всего 10 ссылок в каждой группе
        // т.е. например у нас ссылки 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 - первая группа
        // а 11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20 - вторая и т.д.
        //       определим текущую группу...
        $group = floor($_GET['page'] / 10); //floor округляет до меньшего целого

        //  убедимся в том что мы будем формировать рабочие ссылки...
        if($group*10+10 <= $count) {
            $max = $group*10+10; 
        }
        else {
        //  если же новостей меньше чем $group*10+10, то вычислим последнюю ссылку
            $max = floor($count / 10);
        }
        //   наконецто заполняем массив данными...
        for($i=$group*10; $i<=$max; $i++) {
             $links[] = $i + 1;
        }
        return $links; //возвращаем...

}
?>

Сами видите как много кода, так само много в нем может быть косяков т.к. писал я его прямо на сайте и естественно не тестил, но алгоритм здесь четко прослеживается...
Раз уже так много написал, хотел бы еще написать каким образом выделяется текущая ссылка, например в нашем случае в пагинации... Cредствами JS, например:

<!--Допустим что у нас все ссылки пагинации имеют класс paginationLinks...-->

<script type="text/javascript">
onload = function() {
    getCurrentPaginationLink();
}
function getCurrentLink() {
    links = document.getElementsByClassName("paginationLinks");
    for(var i=0; i<links.length; i++) {
         //в свойстве document.location.href лежит текущий url страницы
         //достаточно просто определить какая именно это ссылка ....
         if(links[i] == document.location.href) {
             //теперь сдесь мы можем определить какой-то особенный стиль
             //для текущей ссылки, длят прмимера просто зальем ее красным...
             links[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
             return;
         }
    }
}
</script>
```

Ознакамливайтесь :)